# Filter data from MongoDB with .NET driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, linq

I need to create a filter for my mongo collection filter. I'm using Mongo driver 2 for .NET.

Here is my JSON.

```
[
    {
        "a": "val_a0",
        "b": "val_b0",
        "arr":[
            {
                "c": "val_c0",
                "d": "val_d0"
            },
            {
                "c": "val_c1",
                "d": "val_d1"
            },
            {
                "c": "val_c2",
                "d": "val_d2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "a": "val_a1",
        "b": "val_b1",
        "arr":[
            {
                "c": "val_c3",
                "d": "val_d3"
            },
            {
                "c": "val_c4",
                "d": "val_d4"
            },
            {
                "c": "val_c5",
                "d": "val_d5"
            }
        ]
    },
...
]
```

I need to apply filter on root level property `a` and nested property `c`. My filter code is:-

```
public class MyFilterClass
{
    public string a { get; set; }

    public MyFilterNestedClass nested { get; set; }
}

public class MyFilterNestedClass
{
    public string c { get; set; }
}
```

And filter code:-

```
public FilterDefinition<MyClass> Build(MyFilterClass filter)
{
    var _filterDef = Builders<MyClass>.Filter.Empty;

    _filterDef &= Builders<MyClass>.Filter.Eq(t => t.a, filter.a); // Filter by root level property [a]

    // Filter by nested level property [c]
    // First way
    _filterDef &= Builders<MyClass>.Filter.Eq(t => t.arr.First(w => w.c == filter.MyFilterNestedClass.c).c, filter.arr.c);

    // Second way
    _filterDef &= builders<MyClass>.filter.where(t => t.a == filter.a &&
                                                    t.arr.first(w => w.c == filter.MyFilterNestedClass.c) != null);

    return _filterDef;
}
```

I tried using both the ways to apply nested property criteria. But it never returns any documents from database.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
var filter = Builders<MyClass>.Filter.And(
            Builders<MyClass>.Filter.Eq(t => t.a, filter.a),
            Builders<MyClass>.Filter.ElemMatch(t => t.arr, i => i.c == filter.nested.c));
return filter;
```

I tested it on similar example I had and It worked so I hope it will work for you as well.

EDIT: seems you need first element explicitly. Sorry I didn't read question with complete understanding. If you want result only if first element matches try this:

```
var filter = Builders<MyClass>.Filter.And(
            Builders<MyClass>.Filter.Eq(t => t.a, filter.a),
            Builders<MyClass>.Filter.Eq(t => t.arr.ElementAt(0).c, filter.nested.c));
return filter;
```

cheers!

Comment: Thanks. First query is what I need. But it returns all the `arr` children objects in result instead of the criteria I applied.

Comment: No problem =). This is just a filter, can you share full code you use to retrieve data?

Comment: This is the code. Included your first snippet. Just class names are different.

Comment: Is thr a way to make is generic using T